# meaning of a large mysql command

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help by describing this php mysql command please:-

```
SELECT itm.*,mem.username as username,cpn.* 
    FROM aw_rdw_items itm,members mem,aw_rdw_items_coupons cpn 
    WHERE itm.item_id=cpn.item_id 
        and item_special_type != 'g' 
        and itm.item_id=cpn.item_id 
        and itm.memberid=mem.memberid 
        and item like('%".addslashes($_REQUEST["item_name"])."%')
        $prs1 $prs2 $greenget $subsql
    ORDER BY Display_Order,itm.item_id ASC
```

Comment: Easy. This php mysql command is wrong.

Comment: begging for expert answers when your question is less than stellar is... not likely to end up well.

Comment: Please ask a new question rather than making a radical edit to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    itm.*, // all columns of table itm
    mem.username as username, // column username and assign the values to a variable called username
    cpn.* // columns of table con
FROM aw_rdw_items itm, members mem, aw_rdw_items_coupons, cpn // tables where execute the research
WHERE itm.item_id=cpn.item_id // various conditions
    and item_special_type != 'g' 
    and itm.item_id=cpn.item_id 
    and itm.memberid=mem.memberid 
    and item like('%".addslashes($_REQUEST["item_name"])."%') // item must contain the specified variable
    $prs1 $prs2 $greenget $subsql // some php variables
ORDER BY Display_Order, itm.item_id ASC // order by Dispay_Order and itm.item_id in ascendant mode
```

Comment: I stripped most of the php part to enable SQL syntax highlight and fixed the comments syntax for SQL

Comment: thanks but actually I have no itm table in my db

Answer (score 0):

Return all records who `item_special_type` is different from `"g"` and `item` contains value from `item_name` request value.

Where clause has another conditions that contained at `$prs1`, `$prs2`, `$greenget` and `$subsql` variables.